# How to save multiple records with stored procedure and transaction and entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an `Event` table and a `Session` table. There are stored procedures `getEvents` and `getEventSessions` to retrive data, so I created C# POCO classes to translate the results of invoking the stored procedures.

```
public class Session 
{
    public DateTime SessionDate { get; set; }
    public string SessionName { get; set; }
}

public class Event 
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public Session[] Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to create new events and sessions. I get an `Event` object with multiple sessions from frontend. How should I save them to databse in one shot?

I googled around, there seems couple of options but I'm confused.

1. create one stored procedure that insert the event, parse and insert the sesssion info that gets passed in by XML or `varchar(max)` parameter.
2. maintain context.Events and context.Sessions, and use context.SaveChanges to update database.
3. create a stored procedure `insertEvent` only for inserting one event, and another stored procedure `insertSession` only for inserting one session. Open a transaction, invoke `insertEvent`, then loop through session list and invoke `insertSession` one by one.

To me, #3 seems the best approach, but I'm very confused how Entity Framework works with transaction in this case. #1 sounds like a very old-school and probably depreciated way. For #2, I think maintaining context.Events and context.Sessions is unnecessary and not consistent with the rest of the project.

Is there a best or better solution for my problem?

Comment: Probably the best option is #2, since you are using EF. All you need to do is to add the Event object to the context, with the Sessions filled.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) to see how to properly arrange a One-To-Many relationship in EF